# splitting names by counting commas gives value error

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have been using this code for this process for around six months and now it is throwing a *ValueError: Columns must be same length as key*. I haven't changed anything so I am not sure what could be wrong. Basically, I am pulling data from my system and it has names formatted like this FN1, FN2 LN1, LN2 and I need the names to be FN1 LN1 and FN2 LN2. The code runs fine until this last line.

```
df_gs_recruiter[[f'Recruiter_{j}']] = df_gs_recruiter[f'FN{j}'] + ' ' + df_gs_recruiter[f'LN{j}']
```

Sample of the data in:

|  | Job ID | Recruiters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 729538 | Bonnie,Tina Smith,Matthews |
| 1 | 720954 | Cindy,Ken Harris,Walsh |
| 2 | 720954 | Cindy,Ken Harris,Walsh |
| 3 | 721061 | Cindy,Ken Harris,Walsh |

```
import numpy as np

num_comma = df_gs_recruiter.Recruiters.str.count(',')

r_min = num_comma.min()
r_max = num_comma.max()
print(r_min,r_max)


df_gs_recruiter[['FN','LN']] = df_gs_recruiter.Recruiters.str.extract('(.*) (.*)',expand=True)
for i in range(len(df_gs_recruiter)):
  r = df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'Recruiters'].count(',')

  if r/2 == 6: 
    df_gs_recruiter[['FN1','FN2','FN3','FN4','FN5', 'FN6', 'FN7']] = df_gs_recruiter.FN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
    df_gs_recruiter[['LN1','LN2','LN3','LN4','LN5', 'LN6', 'LN7']] = df_gs_recruiter.LN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
  elif r/2 == 5: 
    df_gs_recruiter[['FN1','FN2','FN3','FN4','FN5', 'FN6']] = df_gs_recruiter.FN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
    df_gs_recruiter[['LN1','LN2','LN3','LN4','LN5', 'LN6']] = df_gs_recruiter.LN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
  elif r/2 == 4: 
    df_gs_recruiter[['FN1','FN2','FN3','FN4','FN5']] = df_gs_recruiter.FN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
    df_gs_recruiter[['LN1','LN2','LN3','LN4','LN5']] = df_gs_recruiter.LN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
  elif r/2 == 3:
    df_gs_recruiter[['FN1','FN2','FN3','FN4']] = df_gs_recruiter.FN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
    df_gs_recruiter[['LN1','LN2','LN3','LN4']] = df_gs_recruiter.LN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
  elif r/2 == 2:
    df_gs_recruiter[['FN1','FN2','FN3']] = df_gs_recruiter.FN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
    df_gs_recruiter[['LN1','LN2','LN3']] = df_gs_recruiter.LN.str.extract('(.*),(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
  elif r/2 == 1:
    df_gs_recruiter[['FN1','FN2']] = df_gs_recruiter.FN.str.extract('(.*),(.*)',expand=True)
    df_gs_recruiter[['LN1','LN2']] = df_gs_recruiter.LN.str.extract('(.*),(.*)',expand=True)

  df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'num'] = r/2 + 1
  df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'num'].astype(np.int8)
  
  if df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'num'] < 1.5: 
    df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'FN0'] = df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'FN']
    df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'LN0'] = df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'LN']
  else:
    df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'FN0'] = 'null'
    df_gs_recruiter.loc[i,'LN0'] = 'null'

df_gs_recruiter.replace('null', np.nan, inplace=True)
for j in range(0,int(r_max/2)+2):
  df_gs_recruiter[[f'Recruiter_{j}']] = df_gs_recruiter[f'FN{j}'] + ' ' + df_gs_recruiter[f'LN{j}']
```

Expected outcome:
0 4

Then this next part runs and shows the outcome.

```
for col in df_gs_recruiter.columns: 
  if 'Recruiter_' not in col and 'Job ID' not in col:
    df_gs_recruiter.drop([f'{col}'],axis=1, inplace=True)

df_gs_recruiter
```

Expected outcome is:

|  | Job ID | Recruiter_0 | Recruiter_1 | Recruiter_2 | Recruiter_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 729538 | NaN | Bonnie Smith | Tina Matthews | NaN |
| 1 | 720954 | NaN | Cindy Harris | Ken Walsh |  |

Comment: " I haven't changed anything " but have you checked to see if the input data has changed? Has something else been switched upstream from your code that makes some data element have either too many or too few entries for your current code to handle?

Comment: I don't think anything has changed. It's a Google sheet with data coming from Zapier. I haven't added any columns or made any changes to the sheet. It's reading the sheet and fixing the names, etc, and then putting it into another sheet which is a data source for Tableau. After that, I delete the rows from the first sheet and it starts over. I have been running this weekly since September.